# lazySizes + fancybox => img don't load after lightbox

Tags: fancybox, sharepoint-2013, jslink, lazy-loading

I'm using libraries lazySizes and fancybox. Lazyload works good, but when I'm trying to scroll gallery after lightbox, next images won't load.

Also, this construction in the page generated by jslink view (sharepoint 2013) with Image Rendition.

```
<a class='fancybox-thumb' 
   rel='gallery' 
   href='" + itemUrl + "?RenditionID=7' 
   title=''>
   <img class='lazyload' 
        data-src='"+ itemUrl +"?RenditionID=6' 
        style='margin-right: 3px; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;' 
        width=200px 
        height=200px />
</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a link or a testcase?

Comment: Will try to recreate without sharepoint. Tomorrow.

Comment: Is this indeed a duplicate?